# Access return data from resolver in graphql

Tags: graphql

I want to access the country field from my resolver. The country is being returned by query but since `Product` is a list I can only access the object inside `items` return by query. Is there any way I can have access to whole returned data from query or any way to pass it further down as an argument to my resolver function

//schema

```
type ProductCollectionPage {
    items: [Product!]!
}
```

//resolver

```
const resolvers = {
    Product: {
        variants: async (obj: any, args: any, { dataSources }: any): Promise<IProductVariantPage> => {
            const { id } = obj;
            // want to access country here
            return (dataSources.xyz as XyzRepository).retriveProducts(country, id);
        }
    },
    Query: {
        products: async (
            obj: any,
            { id }: { id: string },
            { dataSources }: any
        ): Promise<
            any
        > => {

            const locationDetails = await (dataSources.abc as InventoryLocationsRepository).retrieveInventoryLocation(id);
            const country = locationDetails.country;
            const response = await (dataSources.abc as XyzRepository).retriveProductIds(country);
            // response.list === [{id: 1}, {id:2}]
            return {
                country,
                items: response.list
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `obj` doesn't contain `country`? ... it points to an array only?

Answer (score 0):

As **arrays are objects in javascript** then you can just assign additional property to `response.list`:

```
response.list.country = country;
```